# Can not access metalLB from outside

Tags: kubernetes

I can not access the IP that **metalLB** in **BGP** mode gave to me.
I use virtual router in the doc https://metallb.universe.tf/tutorial/minikube/. I do not use minikube.
What should I do?
I can access the IP in kubernetes cluster but the outside of the cluster it's not accessible.

```
#kubectl get svc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE        NAME                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
default          frontend                 NodePort       10.106.156.219   <none>        80:30001/TCP     4h40m
default          kubernetes               ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          25h
default          mssql-deployment         NodePort       10.98.127.234    <none>        1433:31128/TCP   25h
default          nginx                    LoadBalancer   10.111.123.22    192.168.1.1   80:32715/TCP     4h49m
default          nginx1                   LoadBalancer   10.110.53.202    192.168.1.2   80:31881/TCP     79m
default          nginx3                   LoadBalancer   10.105.73.252    192.168.1.3   80:30515/TCP     77m
default          nginx4                   LoadBalancer   10.102.143.239   192.168.1.4   80:32467/TCP     63m
default          nginx5                   LoadBalancer   10.101.167.161   192.168.1.5   80:30752/TCP     62m
default          nginx6                   LoadBalancer   10.107.121.116   192.168.1.6   80:31832/TCP     61m
default          php-apache               ClusterIP      10.101.18.143    <none>        80/TCP           6h12m
default          redis-master             NodePort       10.98.3.18       <none>        6379:31446/TCP   4h40m
default          redis-slave              ClusterIP      10.110.29.67     <none>        6379/TCP         4h40m
kube-system      kube-dns                 ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP    25h
kube-system      metrics-server           ClusterIP      10.101.39.125    <none>        443/TCP          6h15m
metallb-system   test-bgp-router-bird     ClusterIP      10.96.0.100      <none>        179/TCP          81m
metallb-system   test-bgp-router-quagga   ClusterIP      10.96.0.101      <none>        179/TCP          81m
metallb-system   test-bgp-router-ui       NodePort       10.104.151.219   <none>        80:31983/TCP     81m
```

every nginx IP is available from kubernetes cluster but I can not access them from outside.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: no I try but I can not

Comment: Can you provide ConfigMap from metallb-system namespace? `kubectl get cm -n metallb-system config`

Comment: I do not use minikube